# A book where the earth took revenge on people

Tags: story-identification, books

I don't remember much, but basically the earth was angry about all of the damage we were causing her. I think it started slowly with trees sort of absorbing people. There was something about a scientist figuring out that the earth was about to start taking revenge and trying to warn people. And something about trying to stop a mining operation or some such. That's literally all I remember.

Comment: I bet you can remember more than that.  Who were the heroes? Who were the villains? What were they drilling for? Why was this mine special? Was this written for a younger audience or adults? Was there any swearing? Did the Earth have an actual voice (narrating) or was it all from the perspective of its victims? Was the scientist male or female? Was he/she successful in warning the world? How did they warn people? Where did you read it? When did you read it?

Comment: Maybe he read the book a long, long time ago.

Comment: Heroes-don't remember, or even remember if there were any.
Villains-depends on perspective. Either the earth or humanity as a whole. The earth was retaliating because of how the human race was so bent on destroying it. 
Mine-I only remember it had something to do with removing mountain tops (I think) and what they were mining wasn't important. I think the mine was only added to show how humans were destroying the earth. 
Scientist was male. I think he was only able to warn a small amount of people via word of mouth.
Perspective-victims. No narration from earth. Don't remember about rest.

Comment: No one knows who the heroes were, but we know Dave Lister wouldn't have qualified as such.

Answer (score 2):

This is a long shot, but it sounds like you might be talking about [The Bridge](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/179184.The_Bridge), by John Skipp and Craig Spector. Here are some [highlights](http://www.darkscribemagazine.com/reviews/the-bridge-john-skipp-and-craig-spector.html):

- Toxic waste spill causes a malevolent intelligence to spontaneously emerge
- this intelligence attacks and infects people, which essentially turns them into zombies who sometimes retain parts of their memories and personalities
- much of the story takes place in environemntally damaged areas - dumps, factories, strip mines, and so forth
- there are people who figure out what is going on, not that it helps.

Comment: This isn't it, but it certainly sounds like something I would enjoy reading. Thanks for your answer.